# Invalid operation: relation "fs_fsentry" already exists;

Tags: jcr, iccube

I have an icCube setup, icCubeRepository.xml, to use Postgres as JCR repository. When starting icCube I get the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: Amazon Invalid operation: relation "fs_fsentry" already exists;

Looks as the driver used in the JCR is redshift instead of the expected Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was hapenning because the postgres driver was not added to the classpath in bin/iccube.sh file . Adding postgres jdbc driver to the classpath already available in lib folder of iccube works.